# Why is LINQ-to-Entities is generating an extra left outer join

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities, outer-join

**Background**

I have 2 tables: OrderItem and OrderItemValue.  An OrderItem can have 0 or 1 OrderItemPackageValue.  The Primary key in both tables is the same and there is a foreign key reference from OrderItems to OrderItemPackageValue

**LINQ**

```
var dummy = 
    from orderItem in context.OrderItems
    select new 
    {
        OrderID = orderItem.OrderID,
        LineNumber = orderItem.LineNumber,
        PackageValue = (decimal?)orderItem.OrderItemPackageValue.PackageValue
    };

var dummy2 = dummy.ToArray();
```

**SQL**

```
   SELECT 
   [Extent1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
   [Extent1].[LineNumber] AS [LineNumber], 
   [Extent3].[PackageValue] AS [PackageValue]
   FROM   [dbo].[OrderItems] AS [Extent1]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[OrderItemPackageValues] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[OrderID] =   [Extent2].[OrderID]) AND ([Extent1].[LineNumber] = [Extent2].[LineNumber])
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[OrderItemPackageValues] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[OrderID] = [Extent3].[OrderID]) AND ([Extent2].[LineNumber] = [Extent3].[LineNumber])
```

I'm trying to get this via Linq2Entities (MSSQL) and it seems to be generating an **extra outer join**, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476595) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916830).

Workaround:  Try changing your relationship from `1 : Many` to `0..1 : Many`

Comment: The relationship is 1 to 0..1

Comment: @Adam: Try `0..1 : 0..1`, if that's even possible?  Or `Many : 0..1`?  Again, this is just a workaround, as this should be fixed in the next version.